# How to refresh ContentPage in pure button click handler

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Context**

I would like to diagnose a binding problem. Without exposing the problem details here, I decided to put a diagnostic button on my ContentPage, and would like to write a refresh in the most purest stupidest way, just to see, the already bound content shows up this way or not.

**Question**

So I have my button and its event handler in place, I can not figure out how to call a Refresh or similar?

```cs
public partial class MainView : ContentPage
{
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // I would like to refresh this contentpage here:
    }
}
```

Comment: What is there to refresh ? A list view or some component must be there which must be bound to dynamic. data right ?

Comment: Yes, there is a list, but I would like to refresh the whole page

Comment: If u want to refresh the whole page ,why not trigger an event and go to app.cs page assign a whole new main page .

Comment: Why don't you navigate on the page again in `OnButtonClicked`. You will get a new instance of the page so a "refreshed" page.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be to use `Navigation.PushAsync`, or `App.Current.MainPage = new MainView()` to reset the UI.

But if you want to simply re-construct the view, then I guess calling `InitializeComponent` should do the trick.

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var viewModel = BindingContext;

    BindingContext = null;
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

> **Note:** This code only re-constructs the view (not the bound data) - assuming that you don't want to use the navigation or setting the `MainPage` trick - to refresh the UI.

Comment: Probably don't need InitializeComponent. Setting BindingContext to null, then back to viewModel, should be enough to force all bindings to be refreshed.